# How can I update the table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update, alter-table

I've created a table called Youtuber, the code is below:

```
create table Channel (
    codChannel int primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    age float not null,
    subscribers int not null,
    views int not null
)
```

In this table, there are 2 channels:

```
|codChannel |       name      | age | subscribers |       views |
|     1     |    PewDiePie    | 28  |  58506205   | 16654168214 |
|     2     | Grandtour Games | 15  |       429   |       29463 |
```

So, I want to edit the age of "Grandtour Games" to "18". How can I do that with `update`? 

Is my code right?

```
update age from Grandtour Games where age='18'
```

Comment: You know something I don't.  How would you do this with `alter table`?

Comment: You're right, I forgot that alter table is only for table name or columns. Thanks

Comment: Instead of adding `(CLOSED)` to the title, consider deleting the question.

Comment: `Update channel set age = 18 where codChannel = 2`

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this?????

Comment: Please refrain from spamming version tags unless your question pertains to a specific version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in `update`, you'll have to follow this sequence:

```
update tableName set columnWanted = 'newValue' where columnName = 'elementName'
```

In your code, put this:

```
update Channel set age=18 where name='Grandtour Games'
```

Comments below:

```
/* Channel is the name of the table you'll update

   set is to assign a new value to the age, in your case

   where name='Grandtour Games' is referencing that the name of the Channel you want to update, is Grandtour Games */
```

Comment: columnWanted is the column that has the value I want to update?

Comment: Yes. In your case, is the column age.

Answer (score 0):

`alter table` changes the the schema (adding, updating, or removing columns or keys, that kind of thing).

Update table changes the data in the table without changing the schema.

So the two are really quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer -

```
-> ALTER is a DDL (Data Definition Language) statement 
UPDATE is a DML (Data Manipulation Language) statement.


->ALTER is used to update the structure of the table (add/remove field/index etc). 
Whereas UPDATE is used to update data.
```

Hope this helps!